# How to remove Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) from the search bar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

Today, I was visiting one streaming website and it told me that Edge (EdgeHTML) is not one of its supported browsers. So, I was directed to download Edge (Chromium). I went on to download it and after installation (booom!!) I have two Edge Browsers. Now, I started my quest for finding ways about how to delete the old one, and I came across this: [How to disable or uninstall Microsoft Edge in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10).

I tried the suggested answer and no doubt it worked. I was finally able to disable the Edge (EdgeHTML). I was a happy soul :)

But wait, something more absurd was awaiting. I clicked on the Search Bar and searched "Edge", and guess what? Something related to the older Edge came up right there (the second search result). See this:

[image]

Clicking it doesn't open anything, but it is surely something related to the older Edge. I even tried deleting the components inside the folder of its older version, I mean, deleted all the .exe files inside the folder in this path `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
but, it didn't work. It was still right there, under a name `ms-resource:AppName`.

*So, can anyone guide me in getting rid of this specific search result?*

Comment: The icon of that result is for Chromium Edge not legacy Edge

Comment: I think that's not the case, look the icons - both are clearly different. I am talking about the second search result. That's a legacy edge icon for sure. Isn't that? and the first one is for Edge(Chromium)

Comment: So, can I reset the search cache? How's it done? Can you refer to some sources here on superuser?
Also, I deleted everything from  C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
hoping that the thing will go away. Will it do any problem in future?

Comment: okay, the deleted files are lying in the recycle bin, I will restore it. Can you please tell me how to rebuild my search index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1454651/how-do-i-remove-a-mutant-entry-from-the-windows-10-start-menu/1469209#1469209

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't work for me since I can't delete anything related to Edge through Powershell which the above link suggests. That's what making this case an exception. Can you suggest some other ways please?

Comment: Moreover, I rebuilt search index. Doesn't work.

Comment: I think you downloaded a dud. Chromium Edge has not yet replaced Edge so the original post (the website) is absurd.  Try restore to a prior point.  Advanced System settings, System Protection.

Comment: Unfortunately, after reading your question again, i suspect the behavior you describe, is directly due to removing Edge the way you did.  If you had asked how to disable legacy Edge after installing Chromium Edge I could have helped.  Sadly, the method you used to remove the legacy Edge cannot be reversed.  I will go ahead and cleanup my commentary.  Windows still needs legacy Edge installed but there is indeed a way to hide it (so it doesn't show up in a search), however, it has to be installed for that to work.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, I messed it up. I uninstalled the Edge Chromium and now using the legacy Edge. But, whenever I search for edge, I can find only "ms-resource:AppName" and the only difference now is that it open up edge when I hit enter. Is there no way that I can fix this and get ms-resource:AppName changed to Microsoft Edge :'(    ?

Comment: I would figure out how to reverse the actions you took to uninstall Edge, that should restore search functionality, so 2 applications are found.  Once that works there is a group policy and/or registry key that will hide legacy Edge (i.e. launching Edge in general will launch Chromium Edge).  Since I don't know what method you used to remove Edge, and looking at the solutions in that linked question, I can tell reversing the actions you took will be very difficult I can't provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you so much. If you could find out how to reverse this 'seemingly-irreversible' thing, please let me know :'( and I no longer need Chromium Edge, even if only this legacy Edge gets recovered, I will be happy :(

Comment: I never removed edge, I just tried disabling it using that method given in the question. Everything was fine until I installed the Edge Chromium and disabled Edge Legacy. But when I searched for edge, I saw Microsoft Legacy edge up in the search results (yeah, until then it wasn't ms-resource:AppName, it was just Microsoft Edge) But I tried experimenting and hastily removed the files in this path C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe to recycle bin, and that's where the problem started. After that, whenever I searched edge, it's always ms-resource:AppName.

Comment: By removing that package, you "removed" Edge, but Edge isn't suppose to be removed from the system.  There is a reason it still exists on the system even if you install Chromium Edge.  Was is suppose to happen is, when Chromium Edge is installed, the legacy Edge browser is hidden unless you specifically enable it.

Comment: I understand, I made a blunder. Isn't there any way to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: The problem has bee solved. I don't know how this happened but when I shut down my PC overnight and turned it on the next day, it was fixed automatically. I mean I don't see ms-resource:AppName now, instead I can see the good old legacy edge with proper name.

Comment: If you installed the full release of Edge Chromium it does replace Edge on the system @john. Installing the Deb or other prerelease versions do not.